# R regular L module

Tags: abstract-algebra

Good evening,

in this paper
https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1963-108-02/S0002-9947-1963-0154906-3/S0002-9947-1963-0154906-3.pdf

Rinehart talks about R regular L modules. It's représentation of the Lie algebra $R\oplus L$ together with a R-module structure (Bottom of page 197). I understood that $V(R,L)$ is a R regular L module.

Next, he says that R has a natural R regular L module structure. I don't understand how we can do this. I tried to find a map $\Lambda:R\oplus L\longrightarrow End_K(R)$ using the natural action $a+x\longmapsto \rho(x)(a)$, without succes.

The problem starts at the bottom of the page 197: "A module for R-Lie algebra +[...] Henceforth we will identify R with its image in (,)". Top of the page 198 . In fact, I understood the first story about all (,)-modules are -regular -modules. I can't figure out the "R has a natural structure as an -regular -module".

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you might have forgotten to include the link :).

Comment: Yes thank you :)

Comment: I don't mean to be picky, but could you cite where in the paper you are encountering your problem (if applicable)? This makes it easier for us to follow you and help you.

Comment: The problem starts at the bottom of the page 197: "A module for R-Lie algebra $R + L$[...] Henceforth we will identify R with its image in $V(R,L)$". Top of the page 198 . In fact, I understood the first story about all $V(R,L)$-modules are $R$-regular $L$-modules. I can't figure out the "R has a natural structure as an  $R$-regular $L$-module".

Comment: Great! Add that to your main problem using the edit button.

Comment: Note: not everyone is in the same timezone.